# Xamarin iOS NavigationController returns null

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm still learning the ropes in Xamarin ios and have implemented a side drawer based on the following example [Monotouch.SlideoutNavigation](https://github.com/thedillonb/MonoTouch.SlideoutNavigation). In this tutorial,there's a main view controller class which then assigns a main navigation controller and a side menu.

The drawer menu options are fed into the menu class while the "home screen/first screen" is passed onto the main navigation controller class which is a subclass of a UINavigationController class.

My home screen is a tabcontroller class and I'm trying to make a reference to the navigation controller inside this class but it always returns null.

These are the two challenges I'm facing:

- The navigation controller inside the tab controller and single tab view controllers is always null
- The titles of my individual tab controller classes are not shown on the navigation bar.

Here's the **AppDelegate class** :

```
[Register ("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
        public SlideoutNavigationController Menu { get; private set; }

 public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
                Menu = new SlideoutNavigationController ();

 var tabBarController = GetViewController (Main, "MainTabBarController");

                Menu.MainViewController = new MainNavigationController (tabBarController, Menu);
                Menu.MenuViewController = new MenuNavigationController (new MenuControllerLeft (), Menu) { NavigationBarHidden = true };
                SetRootViewController (Menu, false);

        return true;
    }
}
```

**The MainTabController class**

```
 public partial class MainTabBarController : UITabBarController
{
        UINavigationItem titleRequest,titleHome,titleSell;

  public MainTabBarController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
  //Create an instance of our AppDelegate
         appDelegate = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate;

        //Get an instance of our Main.Storyboard
        var mainStoryboard = appDelegate.Main;

        var tab1 = appDelegate.GetViewController (mainStoryboard, "Tab1");

        var tab2 = appDelegate.GetViewController (mainStoryboard, "Tab2");

        var tab3 = appDelegate.GetViewController (mainStoryboard, "Tab3");


        var tabs = new UIViewController[] {
            tab1, tab2, tab3
        };

        this.SelectedIndex = 1;
        ViewControllers = tabs;
  }

  public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();


            if(this.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {

                titleRequest = new UINavigationItem ("TAB 1");
                this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.PushNavigationItem (titleRequest, true); // NavigationController here is null

            }else if(this.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                titleHome = new UINavigationItem ("TAB 2");
                this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.PushNavigationItem (titleHome, true);


            }else{

                titleSell = new UINavigationItem ("TAB 3");
                this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.PushNavigationItem (titleSell, true);
            }

  }
 }
```

**The MainNavigation controller class**

```
 public class MainNavigationController : UINavigationController
{

 public MainNavigationController(UIViewController rootViewController, SlideoutNavigationController slideoutNavigationController)
        : this(rootViewController, slideoutNavigationController, 

            new UIBarButtonItem(UIImage.FromBundle("icon_sidemenu.png"), UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, (s, e) => {}))
    {
    }
  public MainNavigationController(UIViewController rootViewController, SlideoutNavigationController slideoutNavigationController, UIBarButtonItem openMenuButton)
        : base(rootViewController)
    {
        openMenuButton.Clicked += (s, e) => slideoutNavigationController.Open(true);
        rootViewController.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = openMenuButton;
    }

   public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        this.Delegate = new NavigationControllerDelegate();
        InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Enabled = true;

    }
   public override void PushViewController(UIViewController viewController, bool animated)
    {
        // To avoid corruption of the navigation stack during animations disabled the pop gesture
        if (InteractivePopGestureRecognizer != null)
            InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Enabled = false;
        base.PushViewController(viewController, animated);
    }

    private class NavigationControllerDelegate : UINavigationControllerDelegate
    {
        public override void DidShowViewController(UINavigationController navigationController, UIViewController viewController, bool animated)
        {
            // Enable the gesture after the view has been shown
            navigationController.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit - Results after making changes suggested by Jason below**

[image: Tabs displayed at the bottom the first time but no screen titles]

[image: Tabs disappear after clicking menu options]
Could someone help me see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: it's a little hard to tell what you're doing, but to start with each tab should contain a separate Navigation controller, each of which will contain the view for that tab.  The tab controller itself should be the root view, and it should not be contained in a Nav controller.

Comment: Thanks Jason for your response. I agree with you on the tab controller being the root view and each tab having a Nav controller. I already tried that and would have loved to stick to that. The challenge is that I need to implement a side navigation drawer which has a tab bar controller,and I can't find any implementation on the web where the side drawer isn't the root view. This left me no choice but to have that as the root view instead of the tab bar controller.

Comment: what is MainNavigationController?  Why don't you just assign your tabbar controller directly to Menu.MainViewController?

Comment: It's the navigation controller class. So we're basically passing in  UIViewcontrollers to it so it pushes them onto the stack. I'll add the class up there.

Comment: You can't wrap a tab controller inside a nav controller.  Each tab needs it's own nav controller.

Comment: I know my approach is not using best practices and I also have each tab in its own navigation controller already. Do you have any suggestions to find a work around his example? Or do you know of any examples of a slide out navigation drawer in ios which includes a tab bar controller that you could point me to? I'm basically trying to implement a slide out navigation drawer on my already existing tab bar controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a work around this. For anyone using Dillan's solution and has a TabBarController class as one of the Menu classes, here's how I got it to work.

1. I wrapped the TabBarController class in a NavigationController,apart from the MainNavigationController class. I didn't have to wrap each tab in it's own NavigationController after this.That solves the null reference to the NavigationController inside the TabBarController class
2. To solve the titles being obscured inside each tab, I found a simple solution:

   ```
   public override void ViewDidLoad ()
   {
       base.ViewDidLoad ();

       try{

               this.ViewControllerSelected += (object sender, UITabBarSelectionEventArgs e) => {

               switch(TabBar.SelectedItem.Title)
               {
               case"TAB 1" :

                   Title = "TAB 1";
                   break;

               case "TAB 2":   
                 Title = "TAB 2";
                   break;

               default:
                   Title = "TAB 3";
                   break;
               }
           };


       }catch(Exception e)
       {
           Console.WriteLine (e.Message);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

do this in AppDelegate:

```
    tabs = new UITabBarController();
    tabs.ViewControllers = new UIViewController[]{ 
        new UINavigationController(new UIViewController() { Title = "Tab A" }),
        new UINavigationController(new UIViewController() { Title = "Tab B" }),
        new UINavigationController(new UIViewController() { Title = "Tab C" })
    };

    Menu = new SlideoutNavigationController();
    Menu.MainViewController = new MainNavigationController(tabs, Menu);
    Menu.MenuViewController = new MenuNavigationController(new DummyControllerLeft(), Menu) { NavigationBarHidden = true };
```

Comment: I substituted these changes and the very first time the app is launched, the tabs are displayed at the bottom but no screen titles on the navigation bar. After clicking on the drawer and scrolling through some of the menu options and going back to the home page, the titles are still not present on the navigation bar while the tabs disappear on the bottom. I've added image edits.

Comment: You need to pick a different menu implementation.  I think the one you're using is just not going to work with tabs - it assumes a single navigation controller is being used.  There are several different ones available in the Xamarin Component store.

Comment: Do you have any particular recommendations that would work with tabs? I tried the FlyoutNavigation component already and it  doesn't work well with tabs.

Comment: Thanks Jason for your assistance. I decided to take out the tabs altogether and just go with the menu items.